# how to multiply cost attribute and sold quantity of products in magento reports

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, adminhtml, reports

```
$this->addColumn('cost', array(
    'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Cost'),
    'width'     =>'120px',
    'align'     =>'right',
    'index'     =>'cost * ordered_qty',
    'total'     =>'sum',
    'type'      =>'number'
));
```